# Including Title style in multi-level list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm easily able to create a multi-level list using the heading styles:

[image]

Although I'm wanting to make the Title as part of the multi-level list, so I select the title and make it part of the mutli-level list:

[image]

But, all this does is convert the title to the `Heading 1` style, which although gives the numbering I'm after, is the completely wrong style...

[image]

One work around would be to make the `Heading 1` style the same as `Title` and modify `Heading 1` to appear as `Heading 2` etc... but it really isn't ideal, as the Title is something that I'm wanting occuring as coversheets to the various chapters, and aren't headings of sections as such...

So, how can I make the Title style part of the multi-level list without strange workarounds?

Comment: Keep Title as it's own style but set its heading level to 1. See http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-steps-to-creating-a-numbered-heading-style-in-word/ for some hints.

Comment: Thank you, although that article is not relevant for Word 2010... If you could demonstrate how I could do this in 2010 I would really appreciate it if you could expand it into an answer for me to accept.

Comment: [How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word 2007 and Word 2010](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) covers Word 2010

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a new list style, and include the title on it. [This](https://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) guide is very helpful.

## Creating a new list style

1. To create a new list style, on the Home tab, in the Paragraph group, click the *Multilevel list* menu (not the simple list one).
2. Then, at the bottom, select: *Define new list style*.
3. In the menu that pops up, give your list a name, and, click on the *Format* tab at the bottom left corner of the dialog box, and select *Numbering...*.
4. In the *Modify multilevel list* dialog, click the *More* button.
5. Now, we'll give each level a format:
   5.1 Click the level one on the *Click level to modify* tab, and on the *Link level to style* tab, select *Title*.
   5.2 Click the level two, and on the same tab as before, select *Heading 1*.
   5.3 Repeat this proccess for levels three to nine.
6. Then, we'll set up the numbering:
   6.1 Click the level one to edit it, and on the *Enter formatting for number* space, delete everything.
   6.2 On the level two, select any of the options for *Number style for this level...*. The first one should appear on the *Enter formatting for number box:*.
   6.3 On the level three, click on *Include level number from:*, and select *Level two*. Then, write a full stop (on the *Enter formatting for number* box), and click the desired *Number style for this level*.
   6.4 On the level three click on the *Include level number from:* menu, and select *Level two*. Write a full stop (on the *Enter formatting for number* box), click again on the *Include level number from:* menu, and select *Level three*. Write another full stop, and then select the desired *Number style for this level*.
   6.5 Repeat this for levels four to nine.
7. Finally, we're going to set up the indents:
   7.1 Click on the *Set for all levels* button under position, and on the *Bullet/Number position for first level:* write *0 cm*, on the *Text position for first level:*, write *0 cm*, and, on the *Addicional indent for each level*, write *0.63 cm*.
   7.2 On level one, on the *Follow number with:* tab, select *Nothing*.
8. Click OK and OK to return to the document.

With this, you have your new list, containing the title, ready for use.